# Push code from GitLab to Dokku with different port 22

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, dokku

I use Dokku to host my applications.

I use GitLabto host my code.

I use GitLab-CI for continuous integration.

```
before_script:
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d "\r" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - echo -e "Host $APP_NAME\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\tHostName $HOSTNAME\n\tUser $USERNAME\n\tPort $PORT\n\tIdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
  - ssh-keyscan -H "$HOSTNAME" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

I want push my code to Dokku from GitLab.

```
$USERNAME is dokku
$APP_NAME is hostname in .ssh/config
$APP_NAME_STAGING is name of Dokku application
```

My SSH Dokku server port is 1990 and not 22.

The problem is I must use hostname in config to push on remote repo.

```
$ git-push ssh://$USERNAME@$APP_NAME:$APP_NAME_STAGING master
getaddrinfo example: Name does not resolve
getaddrinfo example: Name does not resolve
getaddrinfo example: Name does not resolve
fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: you might want to add after the echo > .ssh/config a `cat .ssh/config` to see if all variables are resolved, and if HOSTNAME is resolvable

Comment: I have already tried this technique and yes it is resolvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your url syntax is wrong...

The right syntax is `protocol://user@hostname:port/path`, so in your case `ssh://$USERNAME@$APP_NAME/$APP_NAME_STAGING`

With your current syntax it interpret `$APP_NAME:APP_NAME_STAGING` as the hostname, that's why it return `Name does not resolve`

And for custom port (like said above), example :

```
# User:           'dokku'
# Server adress:  'myserver.com'
# Port:           '32'
# Appname:        'myawesomeapp'

ssh://dokku@myserver.com:32/myawesomeapp
```

In your case :

```
ssh://$USERNAME@$APP_NAME:1990/$APP_NAME_STAGING
```

You should take a look to this : https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/master/docs/community/tutorials/deploying-with-gitlab-ci.md